# How to name method used by __init__ to determine value of new object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, casting, type-conversion

I'm new to Python, I started learning Python3.3 few days ago.

Let's have 2 classes, `Source` and `Dest`; `Dest` is declared before `Source`.

I'd like to make a object belonging to class `Dest` with content according to on object belonging to class `Source`.

If it was C++ (which I know quite well), to do thas I could allow casting `Source` to `Dest` by writing `Source::operator Dest()`, `operator Dest(Source)`, `Dest::Dest(Source)`, `operator Dest(Source&)` or `Dest::Dest(Source&)`.

I think about decorating `Dest`'s `__init__` to set `Dest`'s object's value on value returned by passed argument's ***special_method*** (if exist), which should return object with attributes similar to `Dest`'s object.

In code it could look like that:

```
def allow_conversion(prev_init, special_method_name):
    def wrap(self, source, *args, **dic):
        try:
            #call getattr(source, special_method_name)(*args, **dic)
            #copy attributes of returned object (don't know how to implement)
        except Exception: #if getattr(source, special_method_name)
            pass          #doesn't exist or raised Exception
        finally:
            prev_init(source, *args, **dic) #original __init__ is always called
    return wrap

class Dest:
    @allow_conversion('special_method')
    def __init__(self):
        pass #do some initializing
```

**I wonder how to name the *special_method*. Is there any habit?**

Comment: Python uses 'duck typing', meaning that if one object as the methods needed by the caller, it can be used.  It doesn't do static typing.  So, you don't need to 'cast'.  can you give a short example in python code of what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you simply want to create an instance of `Dest` using an instance of `Source`. For that, you should define a class method in `Dest` which takes an instance of `Source` as an argument, and returns a properly initialized instance of `Dest`.

```
class Source:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Dest:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    @classmethod
    def from_source(cls, src):
        return Dest(src.x + src.y)


s = Source(5, 3)
d = Dest.from_source(s)
assert d.a == 8
```

All the logic for "converting" an instance of `Source` to an instance of `Dest` will reside in `Dest.from_source`.

Comment: And when `Dest` is declared before `Source`, I can simply add `Dest.from_source` method in definition of `Source` class.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter which class is defined first, as long as you don't try to *call* `Dest.from_source` until both classes are defined. Techinically, `from_source` doesn't require `src` be an instance of `Source` at all; it just needs `src` to have two attributes `x` and `y` which can be added together. That's what we mean by duck typing.

Comment: I mean: when `Dest` was defined before anyone was thinking about `Source`, so `Dest.from_source` wasn't defined when `Dest` was defined.

Comment: Oh. Well, kind of. It's a little odd to be patching one class from within the definition of another. I might define `from_source` as a regular function outside of `Source`, then follow that with `Dest.from_source = classmethod(from_source)` to patch the `Dest` class. Or you might reverse things a bit: does the method have to be added to `Dest`, or could you define a `to_dest()` method in `Source` which returns an instance of `Dest`. That has the benefit of being a regular instance method, so that you might write something like `d = Source(3, 5).to_dest()`.